# Sharp image uploader not working when running app with PM2

Tags: express, npm, multer

I have an express app that I am using Sharp to resize images after a user has uploaded them.  When I start the app using 'npm start' I am able to upload the images with no issues, but if I use PM2 to manage the process the images don't get saved on the server.  I can save them without using Sharp to resize them, it is only when I have the code for sharp that they don't get saved.  Below is the code from my controller.  Multer is processing the form and sharp is resizing the image.

```
doNewRecipe: function(req, res) {
    for (var key in req.body) {
        req.body[key] = req.body[key] || undefined;
    }
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'title', 'description', 'ingredients', 'instructions', 'yield', 'prep_time', 'cook_time', 'categoryId');
    body.userId = req.session.user.id;

    if (req.file) {
        var tempPath = req.file.path,
            ext = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase(),
            //targetPath = path.resolve(finalUploadPath + req.file.filename + ext);
            targetPath = path.resolve(finalUploadPath);
        fs.renameSync(tempPath, tempPath + ext);
        var newFileName = req.file.filename + ext;
        var imageFile = tempPath + ext;


        body.image = newFileName;

        sharp(imageFile)
            .resize(450, 450)
            .max()
            .toFile('./public/finalUpload/' + newFileName, function(err, info) {
                body.image = newFileName;
                fs.unlinkSync(path.resolve(tempPath + ext));

                db.recipe.create(body).then(function(recipe) {
                    res.redirect('/recipe/view/' + recipe.id);
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                    res.render('error', {message: e.toString()});
                });
            });


        //fs.renameSync(tempPath, targetPath);
    } else {

        db.recipe.create(body).then(function(recipe) {
            res.redirect('/recipe/view/' + recipe.id);
        }, function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            res.render('error', {message: e.toString()});
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you use an ecosystem.json configuration file to start your app with PM2? You could add the CWD parameters.

Comment: I have just been using 'pm2 start bin/www' to start the app.

Comment: it's not the same perform
pm2 start /my/path/app.js
then
cd /my/path; pm2 start app.js
you could generate a json file with the start option of your app and add also the 'cwd' (the path of working directory)

Comment: @AndyBecker I have the same issue, any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use path to determine where to save the file it will transport easily from one system to another.  I actually created a few variables to determine where to save the file.  Below is my code.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   var finalUploadPath = 'hidden';
   var googleTracking = true;
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
   var finalUploadPath = 'hidden';
   var googleTracking = false;
} else {
   var finalUploadPath = 'hidden';
   var googleTracking = false;
}

sharp(imageFile)
            .resize(450, 450)
            .max()
            .toFile(finalUploadPath + req.file.filename + '.jpg', function(err, info) {
                body.image = req.file.filename + '.jpg';
                fs.unlinkSync(path.resolve(tempPath + ext));

                compressAndResize(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/finalUpload/' + body.image));

                db.recipe.create(body).then(function(recipe) {
                    req.flash('success', 'Recipe created');
                    res.redirect('/recipe/view/' + recipe.id + '/' + recipe.slug);
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                    req.flash('error', 'Error creating new recipe');
                    res.render('error', {message: e.toString(), csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), google: googleTracking});
                });
            });
```